# Inheritance: Child uses parent virtual function instead of its own

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I'm having this issue with inheritance I just cannot wrap my head around. I have three classes, with a parental relationship between them. All of them has the function *calcForces()*.

```
class Object {
public:
    virtual void calcForces();
};


class Boat : public Object {
public:
    virtual void calcForces();
};


class Sailboat : public Boat {
public:
    void calcForces(Wind wind);
};
```

Now my problem is that I I have a object created as a *Sailboat* (and saved it in an Object-pointer), but when I call *calcForces()* I end up inside *Boat::calcForces()*, not *Sailboat::calcForces()*. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my call to the function:

```
(*this->object_ptr_arr[i]).calcForces();    //'object_ptr_arr' is of type 'Object**'
```

Comment: You need to call through a pointer for polymorphic behavior. Try: `this->object_ptr_arr[i]->calcForces();`

Comment: Please show a [MCVE].

Comment: To avoid these sort of issues, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The declarations of the overrides must match. Your declaration for `Sailboat::calcForces` takes a different parameter (a `Wind` instance) and therefore is not an override.

As commented by @stefaanv and @skypjack you can avoid this issue by embracing the use of the [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) function specifier, which would've caught the error at compile time.

Comment: I would mention the `override` keyword that serves the purpose of match checking it at compile-time and avoids the error.

Comment: @skypjack Done!

Answer (score 2):

If you want an `calcForces()` method in your sailboat you should add it there.
At the moment you only have a `calcForces(Wind wind)` method in your sailboat (and the `calcForces()` that is inherited from `Boat`)

So when you are calling `calcForces` without a parameter it will end up in the inherited method. To fix this either add it in `Sailboat` like described above or call it with an variable of type `Wind`

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion - boats and sailboats exist in an environment. The boat knows how it is affected by the environment.

```
class Environment
{
public:
  Wind wind;
};

class Object {
public:
    virtual void calcForces(Environment const&);
};


class Boat : public Object {
public:
    virtual void calcForces(Environment const& env); // can ignore the wind
};


class Sailboat : public Boat {
public:
    void calcForces(Environment const& env) override;  // will use env.wind in calculation
};
```

Now you are able to modify the environment and ask all objects in the environment to calculate their forces. Whether they're boats, sailboats or dolphins.

Comment: Very good suggestion and definitely preferable because of the object-orientated approach. But that isn't very helpful if he is facing similiar problems in the future because it doesn't describes what he was doing wrong.